# Call a Java app with a parameter but never wait for the answer

Tags: java, php

What I want to do is when an user logs in to call a Java app from the PHP server. The app to index some content and process it and save it to a database. But what I want to really do, is to call it and nevermind what it does and never wait for the answer. Like a cronjob on demand. Is this possible?

UPDATE:

Is shell_exec a solution? 
$res = shell_exec('java Myprogram');

Comment: What are you talking about: The user logs into a site served by a PHP webserver? Or do you mean the user uses shell access (e.g. ssh)? Where shall the app run? On the client side? On the server side?

Comment: Both PHP and Java on server-side. The website runs on PHP and Java does the processing(data that the app should process before the user asks for it). Do you get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really matter if you are running java or anything else. You need to run new process in background. You can do it with [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). There are a lot of examples in comments there, but you basically need to do:

```
exec("java Foo > /dev/null &")
```

Comment: I don't think exec will do what he wants, unless it's preceded by a fork (which I don't have much Java or PHP knowledge on). Exec (in C) replaces the current process with another, and doesn't allow execution to continue.

Comment: @dcpomero `&` will do the job. It's shell's equivalent of fork. [See here](http://hacktux.com/bash/ampersand).

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that was how exec behaved with background tasks. I downvoted you, but I can't change it unless you edit your response.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, what you should do is to **spawn a Thread** for the desired processing, and return from the called method.